# Anonymous code blocks in c

Tags: c, macros, anonymous-function, parentheses

What does a statement such as this mean ?

```
int x  = ( { int a; scanf( "%d", &a ); a ; } ) ;
```

It compiles and runs equivalent to :

```
int x;
scanf( "%d", &x );
```

It seems to be like some kind of anonymous function call or something, but I'm not sure. I have not come across statements like `({})` before, and I am unable to find any explanations online. Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you :)

**Context:**

This is the code that you get when the macros in the following code are expanded :

```
#define SI ({int a;scanf("%d",&a);a;});
int x = SI;
```

This is the code used by someone in a programming competition.

Comment: Is that programming competition the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/)?

Comment: @ObscureRobot: actually, in programming competitions you see lots of such macros, it's simply for reading the input easier and faster (time is often very limited so you don't want to waste it with "nice" wrappers). Doesn't have to be an IOCCC comp necessarily, I've written enough ugly code myself in such comps :p. Here probably some idiot thought macros were fasters than inlines...

Comment: The real question: why not make it an inline function... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird C++ Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305396/weird-c-syntax)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an **Statement Expression.**
It as an compiler extension supported by GCC and it is not Standard C++,hence it is non portable.
If you compile your code with the `-pedantic` flag it will tell you so.

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305396/weird-c-syntax/6305429#6305429)** answer of mine talks about it in detail.

Comment: Just noticed that the Q was re-tagged to just `C`,So to be clear `Statement Expressions` are not Standard C or Standard C++.

Comment: What one maybe can mention is the reason for using it. For "void" macros that require multiple statements you can use the do-while-loop-construct to make the macro "behave" like a function call. This is portable, but when you need to return a value, this is the only possible way to achieve it (afaik).