# Strange C/C++ syntax

Tags: c++, c, gcc, syntax, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's this C++ syntax that puts a brace-surrounded block where an expression is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305396/weird-c-syntax)

I've just come across this strange C/C++ syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%s",
        ({
        static char b__[129];
        b__[0] = 55;
        b__[1] = 55;
        b__[2] = 0;
        b__;
        })
    );
}
```

This compiles and runs fine using both gcc and g++ (4.5.2). This is the first time I see something like this, and I wonder what exactly this syntax means. I've tried to Google it, but I have no idea what this construct is called.

Comment: This is 100% a dupe, just have to find it...

Comment: Well, I've come across this piece of code at: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50179.

Comment: @Xeo This time it's "Weird C Syntax" only :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They're called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), it's a GNU extension. In your example the result of the expression is `b__`.

Comment: I would add that they are very convenient when used in macros, since they allow macros to act (almost) like functions returning a result.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Yup, I especially like the `maxint` macro example in the docs.

Comment: So is that how shorthand lambdas work?