# What does #define FOO(x,c) (void)( { c = ( x ) ; }) do?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was looking at the Linux source and the following line seemed strange. 
What may be the use of the `(void) ( { .... ;} )` construct?

```
#define GETCH(queue,c) \
        (void)({c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);})
```

Here is what I think:

**1.** `(void)` suppresses some compiler warnings.

**2.** `{....}` is there to group the two statements together, so that it can use used like `while(...) GETCH(q,c);` correctly.

Is there any other reason? Is there any documentation available?

Source: [Linux-0.01 Source - GitHub](https://github.com/zavg/linux-0.01/blob/master/include/linux/tty.h)

Comment: The magic are the outer parenthesis: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs "*StatementExpressions*" are an extension to the C standard.

Comment: You're 100 % correct

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You should not have closed this as a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compound-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c). The statement-expression extension only answers part of this question. Overtly, there is no reason to use a statement-expression in this macro: It would perform the same operations with just braces. The macro forms a grammatical entity that, when followed by a semicolon, forms a single statement and so can be used in place of `S` in `if (X) S; else T;`, which would not be true with braces alone.

Comment: Well then you search the proper duplicate

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Or we could, you know, answer the question. Correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced C question: Please explain C construct \*({ foo(&bar); &bar; })](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487415/advanced-c-question-please-explain-c-construct-foobar-bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this macro, the author uses a GCC “statement expression” extension to do two things:

- Supply two statements, an assignment (`c=…`) and a use of the `INC` macro, which I presume performs some increment to its argument.
- Package those two statements so that, when followed by a semicolon, they form a single statement.

The reason for the latter to allow this macro to be used in places like this:

```
if (some expression)
    GETCH(queue,c);
else
    some other statement;
```

For example, suppose the macro had been written using normal braces, like this:

```
#define GETCH(queue,c) \
    {c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);}
```

Then it would supply both statements and group them, so we could use them in simple code like this:

```
statement X;
GETCH(queue,c);
statement Y;
```

However, consider the consequences in the `if` statement. We would have

```
if (some expression)
    {c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);};
else
    some other statement;
```

There is a problem: `{ … }` and `;` are **two** statements. The `;` is an empty expression statement. And you cannot have two statements between an `if` and an `else`. The compiler will emit a warning when it sees the `else` after the two statements. But the author of `GETCH` wanted you to be able to use the macro followed by a semicolon as one statement—they wanted it to “look like” a function call, which you can follow with a semicolon.

So, the author did something else. They used a feature of GCC called a statement expression. It is not a part of the C standard; it is an extension defined by GCC.  When using GCC, a compound statement (a statement in braces, `{ … }`) that ends with an expression statement and is enclosed in parentheses (`({ … })`) acts like an expression whose value is the last expression statement inside the braces. For example `({ if (x) z=x*x; else z=5; 3*z; })` acts like an expression with the value `3*z`, in addition to perform the statements inside the braces. Because this is a single expression, you can follow it with a semicolon to form a single statement.

So, if the author had written:

```
#define GETCH(queue,c) \
    ({c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);})
```

then we could write:

```
if (some expression)
    GETCH(queue,c);
else
    some other statement;
```

The author also included a cast to `(void)`:

```
#define GETCH(queue,c) \
    (void)({c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);})
```

I expect the purpose of that is to prevent the expression statement from being used as an expression—the author only wanted it to act in the grammar as a single statement and did not want its resulting value used.

That said, I do not see why the author chose to use a GCC extension for this. There is a well known way of doing this in standard C:

```
#define GETCH(queue,c) \
    do {c=(queue).buf[(queue).tail];INC((queue).tail);} while (0)
```

The statement inside the `do` will be executed just once (because it is executed first, then the `while` expression is checked, and it is false, so no loop occurs), and following the above with a semicolon forms a single statement.