# Why this compound statement as a sequence of statements enclosed by braces and inside parentheses does not appear to be a valid statement expression

Tags: c++, expression, braces, gcc-extensions

Why this compound statement  as a sequence of statements enclosed by braces (in GNU C++) and inside parentheses does not appear to be a valid Statement expression.

```
// my second program in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout << "Hello World! ";
  ({cout << "I'm a C++ program";}); 

}
```

Compiler output:

```
 In function 'int main()':
8:32: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ostream<char>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:58:11: note: 'std::basic_ostream<char>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:58:11: error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: note: 'std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: error: 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/basic_ios.h:66:11: error: within this context
     class basic_ios : public ios_base
           ^
```

I have found a good answer about 'statement expression' in [What's this C++ syntax that puts a brace-surrounded block where an expression is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305396/whats-this-c-syntax-that-puts-a-brace-surrounded-block-where-an-expression-is)

Comment: Aside: I hope this is not *actually* your second c++ program. You should learn more of the language before you learn compiler specific extensions.

Comment: @cigien: An expert in computer science generally might take up a new language and jump to extensions immediately. The question posed is sensible, and there is no reason to jump to conclusions about the asker.

Comment: That comment could also be a joke, of course...

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's fair. I meant that it might be easier to understand what the language extension is doing, if you know more about the language, but I suppose there's no harm in trying to understand the particular extension anyway. It's definitely a valid, and well asked question.

Comment: @NateEldredge Well, I was being serious, but I suppose the tone could have been less judgemental. I'll try and bear that in mind in the future.

Comment: Guys, it does not matter, the base example is from here: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/
Very convenient site for testing examples.

Answer (score 7):

From the [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs):

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

and

> In G++, the result value of a statement expression undergoes array and function pointer decay, and is returned by value to the enclosing expression.

This means in the expression:

```
({cout << "I'm a C++ program";});
```

the object `std::cout` is returned by *value*. This invokes the copy constructor of `std::basic_ostream`, which is deleted, and hence the error.

Comment: So, `({void(cout<<"I'm a C++ program");});`

Comment: @jthill Or just `({cout << "I'm a C++ program"; ; });`. But I think this is mostly an academic question, and the OP is not actually looking for a fix.

Comment: The question came up because I read a c++ wrapper for gnu prolog on GitHub and found 'statement expression' in it. That was a feature that I didn't use much in the past and I started testing it a bit. Coincidentally, I came across an unexpected error message. The explanation is a bit above my capabilities, but basically I understand that not everything works very simply. It will be enough for me to stick to simpler constructions. Good style to follow anyway. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)